# how can i debug why things keep getting removed from my asp.net-mvc cache

Tags: asp.net-mvc, memory, windows-server-2008, outputcache

is there anyway to look on a windows web server to see the current size of the asp.net cache and how much room it has left before things keep getting rejected.

I set to cache objects for 48 hours but i keep seeing web pages load slow so somehow things are getting removed from the cache. (i am passing a variable down to the view that indicates whether it got the result set from the cache or not.  one I load a page, i would expect that to be True for the next 48 hours but it doesn't seem to be happening.

any suggestions on how i can debug this further to figure out next steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET will cache to memory by default, you can add caching to disk, but it is much slower and you will need to write or find a provider.

ASP.NET can remove data from the cache for one of these reasons:

- Because memory on the server is low,
  a process known as scavenging.
- Because the item in the cache has
  expired.
- Because the item's
  dependency changes.

To help you manage cached items, ASP.NET can notify your application when items are removed from the cache.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178597.aspx

**Where Content is Cached**

By default, when you use the [OutputCache] attribute, content is cached in three locations: the web server, any proxy servers, and the web browser. You can control exactly where content is cached by modifying the Location property of the [OutputCache] attribute.

You can set the Location property to any one of the following values:

- Any
- Client
- Downstream
- Server
- None
- ServerAndClient

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs

**More information**

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/web-cache/cachemanagementinaspnet.aspx